# Whitespace in filenames in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script that processes some files.  The problem is that there might be white spaces in file names, I did:

```
#!/bin/sh
FILE=`echo $FILE | sed -e 's/[[:space:]]/\\ /g'`
cat $FILE
```

So the variable `FILE` is a file name which is passed in from some other program.  It may contain white spaces.  I used `sed` to escape white space with `\` in order to make the command line utilities be able to process it.

The problem is that it doesn't work.  `echo $FILE | sed -e 's/[[:space:]]/\\ /g'` itself works as expected, but when assigned to `FILE`, the escape char `\` disappeared again. As a result, `cat` will interpret it as more than 1 arguments.  I wonder why it behaves like this?  Is there anyway to avoid it?  And what if there're multiple white spaces, say `some   terrible  file.txt`, which should be replaced by `some\ \ \ terrible\ \ file.txt`. Thanks.

Comment: Use more quotes. http://shellcheck.net/ will catch this category of bug automatically.

Comment: And escape characters inside of variables are utterly useless -- escapes and quotes are *code syntax*; if syntax embedded in variable contents were honored on expansion, writing secure code in shell-derived languages would be effectively impossible, because such data could escape its quoting, perform its own expansions, and otherwise do all the evil that's presently only possible with `eval`. See BashFAQ #50 at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: BTW, if your shebang is `#!/bin/sh`, this isn't a bash script, it's a POSIX sh script. It's only a bash script if it starts with `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Also, don't use all-uppercase names for your own variables. See the relevant standards document at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html -- amongst environment variables, all-uppercase variables are used by the shell and system, and lowercase names are reserved for user use. Shell variables share a namespace with environment variables, so this convention applies to them as well to avoid accidentally overwriting variables with meaning to the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t make it more complicated than it is.

```
cat "$FILE"
```

That’s all you need. Note the quotes around the variable. They prevent the variable from being expanded and split at whitespace. You should always write your shell programs like that. Always put quotes around all your variables, unless you really want the shell to expand them.

```
for i in $pattern; do
```

That would be ok.

Comment: `for i in $pattern; do` is fairly unfortunate too -- you can't represent patterns like `"hello world"*.txt` that way. Better to expand into an array and iterate over the array's contents.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to put escape characters inside your data -- they're only honored as syntax (that is, backslashes have meaning when found in your *source code*, not your data).

That is to say, the following works perfectly, exactly as given:

```
file='some   terrible  file.txt'
cat "$file"
```

...likewise if the name comes from a glob result or similar:

```
# this operates in a temporary directory to not change the filesystem you're running it in
tempdir=$(mktemp -d "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/testdir.XXXXXX") && (
  cd "$tempdir" || exit
  echo 'example' >'some  terrible  file.txt'
  for file in *.txt; do
    printf 'Found file %q with the following contents:\n' "$file"
    cat "$file"
  done
  rm -rf "$tempdir"
)
```